# using pipx to install openpyxl for homebrew-installed python

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, openpyxl, pipx

I am using `openpyxl` to automate a few routine tasks on my own machine. It was working to install with pip, making it available across the machine. I understand that installing without a virtual environment is not recommended nor allowed with python installed by homebrew.

Now I'm trying `pipx`. But `pipx install openpyxl` produces `No apps associated with package openpyxl or its dependencies.`

Here are my questions about deploying python modules like openpyxl for a script like this:

1. Is there another way to install openpyxl with pipx?
2. If installing openpyxl with pipx is not recommended, what is the best way to make openpyxl available to the homebrew-installed python?
3. If it using openpyxl requires a virtual environment, does that mean the environment must be activated every time the script runs?

Comment: Openpyxl is just a normal Python package and doesn't require anything special to install.